# Jinja2 NativeTemplate rendering strings with double quotes issue

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, literals

I'm reading a path value from Postgres DB (column type **String**).

For example:
path | "G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx"

The problem is that some of the nested directories in the path starts with integer (as the above), and Python automatically treats those as Hex characters.

\2 is converted to \x02.
\08 (treated as \0) converted to \x008
\2021 (treated as \20) converted to \x821

```
print(repr('"G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx"'))

> '"G:\\Shared drives\x02 test\x821\x008.2021\test.xlsx"'
```

How can I stop Python from interpreting these hex values, and treat it as raw string?

Expected result:

```
'"G:\\Shared drives\\2 test\\2021\\08.2021\test.xlsx"'
```

**Edit:**
It seems that the value is correct on the DB side, and also when I read it.

The path is getting corrupted **once I render it with Jinja2 NativeTemplate (specifically native template)**.

```
import jinja2
 
env = jinja2.nativetypes.NativeEnvironment()
path = '"G:\\Shared drives\\2 test\\2021\\08.2021\\test.xlsx"'

print(path)
> "G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx"

t = env.from_string('{{ path }}')
result = t.render(path=path)

print(result) # result is broken
> G:\Shared drives test18.2021  est.xlsx

print(repr(result))
> 'G:\\Shared drives\x02 test\x821\x008.2021\test.xlsx'
```

If I remove the double quotes from the path string, the render output is valid:

```
path = 'G:\\Shared drives\\2 test\\2021\\08.2021\\test.xlsx'
result = t.render(path=path)

print(result) # works without double quotes
> G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx
```

**Update:**

The issue source is the native_concat method in jinja's NativeEnvironment.

The method returns the **literal_eval** of the input.

```
try:
    return literal_eval(out)
```

Reproduce:

```
path = '"G:\\Shared drives\\2 test\\2021\\08.2021\\test.xlsx"'

print(literal_eval(path))
> G:\Shared drives test18.2021  est.xlsx

print(repr(literal_eval(path)))
> 'G:\\Shared drives\x02 test\x821\x008.2021\test.xlsx'
```

Comment: ``\2`` only has meaning of ``\x02`` in a string *literal*. If you fetch data from a DB and it contains a ``\`` followed by a ``2`` that's not going to be re-interpreted by Python. Can you please provide a [mre] in which you are actually dealing with non-literal data, the way that data would be provided by a DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised the issue to Jinja, and got the following answer:
https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/1518#issuecomment-950326763

"This is due to the way escapes work when parsing Python strings. You need to double up the \\"

Indeed, doubling the backslashes did the trick:

```
path = '"G:\\\\Shared drives\\\\2 test\\\\2021\\\\08.2021\\\\test.xlsx"'
print(literal_eval(path))

# output:
> G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx
```

And if I want to keep the double quotes:

```
path = '"\\"G:\\\\Shared drives\\\\2 test\\\\2021\\\\08.2021\\\\test.xlsx\\""'
print(literal_eval(path))

# output
> "G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` starts an escape sequence in a Python string literals. To prevent this, you have roughly four options:

1. Properly escape your string. That is, double up every path separator backslash: `'"G:\\Shared drives\\2 test\\2021\\08.2021\test.xlsx"'`
2. Use raw strings to prevent escape sequences from being interpreted: `r'G:\Shared drives\2 test\2021\08.2021\test.xls'`
3. Use forward slashes instead of backslashes, which are valid as Windows paths: `'G:/Shared drives/2 test/2021/08.2021/test.xls'`
4. Don’t use string literals in your Python code; instead, read the string from some other source (e.g. user input or a file).

Comment: "Don’t use string literals in your Python code" Apparently they already do: "I'm reading a path value from Postgres DB"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I agree, OP needs to provide some clarification. That said, it’s fairly clear from their description that the issue is actually caused by *string literals*.

Comment: I'm reading the path from the DB, and I'm asking how to escape \ replace those hex characters to be treated as raw strings on the flight.

Comment: @YoavSheetrit So the "hex characters" are already in the DB data?

Comment: The DB value is a valid string as it should be.

I found now that the issue source is jinja2 NativeEnvironment template rendering. Still not sure why it happens (doesn't reproduce when using jinja2.Environment instead of NativeEnvironment)

Answer (score -1):

s = "C:\Program Files\norton\appx"

print(s)

s = r"C:\Program Files\norton\appx"

print(s)